# Repopulate values in select field

Tags: php, laravel-4

I want to repopulate the old value after validation.I have tried many options and I am not getting.

Here is my code

```
select name="Skills[]" class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple" id ="Skills"
@foreach($skills as $skill)
option value="{{$skill->skill_id}}" >{{$skill->skill_name}}</option>            
@endforeach         
/select
```

Answer (score 0):

correct me if I'm wrong but what you mean by **repopulate the old value** is to show as selected the option chosen by the user after validation right?

if so then you can try after redirecting to a View the following:

```
    <?php $i=1; ?>
    <select name="Skills[]" class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple" id ="Skills">
      @foreach($skills as $skill)
        <option value="{{$skill->skill_id}}" @if($skill->skill_id==$i++){'selected="selected"'}@endif>{{$skill->skill_name}}</option>
      @endforeach
    </select>
```